# Q: How to remove login in IIS Application

Tags: authentication, iis

I've inherited an old asp.net application which runs on IIS v10, but I've run into a problem trying to remove the authentication. The application runs under the Default Web Site. It was originally set to Windows Authentication and worked, but now I need to remove the login that occurs on load of the website.

The Default Web Site (app parent) authentication is set to Anonymous. When I disable all authentication at the application level, I get a 401 - Unauthorized User error in the browser. When I enable Anonymous authentication, the site loads very slow, but only the HTML with none of the CSS styling. I'm not sure why this is.

How should the authentication be configured to remove a login?

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose the application which under the Default Web Site and click the Authentication module.
[image]

In addition to disabling windows authentication, also enable anonymous authentication.
[image]

If you want to disable windows authentication for a file in the application, first select the content view to view the files inside the application, then select the file and right-click the switch to features view.

[image]